# Find a Lebesgue measurable function $\phi$ such that $\int_0^\infty \phi(x) f(x) dx < \infty$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $f$ be a nonnegative Lebesgue measurable function on $[0, \infty)$ such that $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx < \infty$. Show that there exists a positive, nondecreasing, Lebesgue measurable function $\phi$ on $[0, \infty$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \phi(x) = \infty$, and such that $\int_0^\infty \phi(x) f(x) dx < \infty$.

This problem is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164555/show-there-exists-a-positive-strictly-increasing-measurable-function) but I want to solve the problem by contructing $\phi$ explicitly.

We can write $[0, \infty) = \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} [n, n+1)$ and then define $\phi(x) = n$ for $x \in [n, n+1)$. But then I don't know how to prove that $\int_0^\infty \phi(x) f(x) dx < \infty$ or if my example of $\phi$ will actually work.

Answer (score 1):

That example will not work, and any answer for $\phi$ you get must depend on $f$. For your example take $f(x) = \frac{1}{n^2}$ for $x \in [n, n + 1)$ (and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in [0, 1)$). Then
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \phi(x) f(x) \, \text{d}x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} = \infty $$

Comment: Do you think it's a good idea to partition $[0, \infty)$ into the disjoint intervals $[n, n+1)$? I'm also not sure how to choose $\phi$ based on $f$ since $phi$ needs to approach $\infty$ and I don't know much about $\phi$.

Comment: No, the sequence $(0, 1, 2, \ldots)$ is too arbitrary. You need to partition into $[a_n, a_{n+1})$ where $(a_n)$ is a sequence depending on $f$. Actually the first answer in your link explains the idea pretty well.